# How to group a df based on one column and apply a function to another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am quite new to pandas here, I have been stuck for weeks in this issue, so as a last resort i have come to this forum.

Below is my dataframe

```
    S2Rate  S2BillDate  Sale Average    Total Sale
0   20.00   2019-05-18  20.000000         20.00
1   15.00   2019-05-18  26.250000         420.00
2   15.00   2019-05-19  36.000000         180.00
3   7.50    2019-05-19  34.500000         172.50
4   7.50    2019-05-21  32.894737         625.00
```

I am trying to plot a graph where my primary y axis will have the S2rate and secondary Yaxis will have sale average. But I would like my x axis to have the date , for which I will need my df to like like  this(below)

```
    S2Rate  S2BillDate                  Sale Average    Total Sale
0   20.00   2019-05-18                  20.000000         20.00
1   15.00   2019-05-18 to 2019-05-19    31.1250000        600.00

2   7.50    2019-05-19 to 2019-05-21    33.690000         797.50
```

That is for S2rate 15 min date is 2019-05-18 and max date is 2019-05-19, so it needs to pic the min and max date for the S2rate that needs to be grouped, cause there can be situations when for a same S2rate, there can be many days.

Can anyone guide me towards this, also please do not mistake that I am directly asking help/code, even pointing me to the right concepts will do. I kinda have no clue how to proceed further.

Any help is much appreciated. TIA !

Comment: Is it possible for S2Rate to repeat previous values? E.g., S2Rate=15.00 in 2019-05-22 and 2019-05-23.

Comment: @BillHuang Yes , S2Rate can repeat itself, S2rate is nothing but price of the item across different dates, for example S2rate can be 5 for dates 01-Oct-2020 , 02-Oct-2020, 03-Oct-2020...10-Oct-2020. So I need to pick min and max date for that S2rate

Comment: No. I mean, could there be **multiple groups** of S2Rate? Like, Oct.1-Oct.10 is a group, but then another group recurrs in Nov.1-Nov.10. Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah that could be possible

Comment: OK in that case the diff-cumsum trick must be done. I have greatly simplified the syntax in the answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since `S2Rate` values can recur, **consecutive** dates of a `S2Rate` must be identified first. This can be done by a `diff-cumsum` trick. *Ignore this step if you'd like to group by all `S2Rate`s*.

```
# identify consecutive groups of S2Rate
df["S2RateGroup"] = (df["S2Rate"].diff() != 0).cumsum()

df
Out[268]: 
   S2Rate  S2BillDate  Sale Average  Total Sale  S2RateGroup
0    20.0  2019-05-18     20.000000        20.0            1
1    15.0  2019-05-18     26.250000       420.0            2
2    15.0  2019-05-19     36.000000       180.0            2
3     7.5  2019-05-19     34.500000       172.5            3
4     7.5  2019-05-21     32.894737       625.0            3
```

Next, just write your custom title-producing function and put it into `.agg()` using [Named Aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
def date_agg(col):
    dmin = col.min()
    dmax = col.max()
    return f"{dmin} to {dmax}" if dmax > dmin else f"{dmin}"

df.groupby("S2RateGroup").agg(  # or .groupby("S2Rate")
    s2rate=pd.NamedAgg("S2Rate", np.min),
    date=pd.NamedAgg("S2BillDate", date_agg),
    sale_avg=pd.NamedAgg("Sale Average", np.mean),
    total_sale=pd.NamedAgg("Total Sale", np.sum)
)
# result
Out[270]: 
             s2rate                      date   sale_avg  total_sale
S2RateGroup                                                         
1              20.0                2019-05-18  20.000000        20.0
2              15.0  2019-05-18 to 2019-05-19  31.125000       600.0
3               7.5  2019-05-19 to 2019-05-21  33.697368       797.5
```

Since you are new to pandas, it would also be helpful to go through the [official how-to](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Huang ! I really appreciate your help.